# Access class/function from mysql database with/without using eval

Tags: php, mysql, function, eval

I am making a CMS and am having trouble, I have the about page as my home page and making another page for my blog, however, I need to store

```
<?php $obj->blog_posts(); ?>
```

in the database and then access by calling the `get_content()` function

Comment: I do not understand what your question is

Comment: I do not know what you really want to do, but these links could be usefuls [serialize](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) [_sleep](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) [_wakeup](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to store that. Instead, you need to store a token such as `%BLOGPOSTS%` and you need a template engine that will replace the token with the result of that method call.

Comment: can you please explain further?